# Why my webpage url and its children are not working in production

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, hosting, production

I bought a domain that offers HTTP service. I created an Angular website and built it `ng build --prod`.

The host file system is the following:

```
- private
- public
     - www
         - assets
         - scripts.js
         - index.html
         - ...
```

The website resides inside the www folder. The folder has the scripts the Html and all the files/folders.

The URL is `www.myurl.com`, when I access the URL it goes to the home page and changes the URL to `www.myrurl.com/home`. If I refresh the page it throws ERROR 404, or even if I access the page `www.myurl.com/register` which exists.

I do not know what to put in my base URL or if even built it right.

Comment: What is `baseUrl` in `index.html`

Comment: @ahmeticat at the moment its just "/"

Comment: Is there any `web.config` file?

Comment: @ahmeticat no there is not

Comment: Please try the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add `web.config` file in your host where `index.html` path.

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: added the `web.config` but it didn't work. Do I need to change the base URL?

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend of which web server is used. You can access to your application when loading `/` url because the web server is fetching `index.html` file.
But when you're loading another page, the server doesn't know which file it should fetch.

So you need to add some configuration to redirect all your request to `index.html`

**Apache**

add `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

**Nginx**

Use try_files

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

To know more, read about deployment procedure in angular doc : https://angular.io/guide/deployment